# How to log an exception without a controller in asp.net mvc 3 when using customErrors mode="on"?

Tags: logging, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-3

I've read a lot of material today on the topic of implementing custom error pages in ASP.NET MVC (using 3 RC2). One thing I want to be able to do is log exceptions, but I'm not sure where the best hook is.

I mainly followed [Barry Dahlberg's advice](http://www.genericerror.com/blog/2009/01/27/ASPNetMVCCustomErrorPages.aspx) which helped me set up the desired 404 behaviors. I want to keep those separate from server errors, and log them differently.

It seems that when I have <customErrors mode="On">, MVC3 just uses the view defined at ~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml, passing the correct System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo model instance. In effect, this is bypassing the controller where I would put the error logging code.

I tried setting <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="errors/unexpected" />, but the controller action method never gets invoked.

The HandleErrorInfo model in the view has the exception information I need for logging. I could log the error in the view, but that smells funny.

Another solution would be to keep <customErrors mode="Off" />. Since this causes Application_Error to be invoked from Global.asax, I could log there instead.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a [custom HandleError](http://blog.dantup.com/2009/04/aspnet-mvc-handleerror-attribute-custom.html) attribute where you would log the exception in the overriden [OnException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute.onexception.aspx) method.

Comment: That's the article I was looking for. Guess I just didn't use the right search options, thanks.